# Issue installing modem ZTE AC682 UI on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: installation, modem

Unable to make connection to Internet using my modem
**ZTE AC682 UI** on **Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS**

```
iwan@iwan-Quadra-NE-1003:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 10f1:1a21 Importek 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 19d2:ffdd ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
iwan@iwan-Quadra-NE-1003:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check this [link](http://ubuntu.igameilive.com/2012/08/zte-ac-682-in-ubuntu-1204.html) or on [this](http://ifannuddin.blogspot.com/2012/05/setting-modem-smartfren-ac682-di-ubuntu.html) for Indonesian language.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.